# Array issue in JS

Tags: javascript, api

I ran into an issue where I can't figure out how to pull the data from a TPA API. Would greatly appreciate any help!:)
This is the link to the API: https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php

I'm trying to pull out the name of the meal, instructions picture, and the source of the recipe, using an ajax method.

This is the basic structure I have right now:

```
let randomGenerator = function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php",
        success: function(r){
            console.log(r);
        let meals = r["meals"]
        let pic = meals[34]
        let name = meals[23]
        let instructions = meals[29]
        let source = meals[52]
        $("#random-name").html(name)
        $("#random-description").html(instructions)
        $("#random-source").html(source)
        $("#random-photo").attr("src", pic)
        },
        error: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }
  });
  
  }
```

This is the result from the API when fetched from above link:

```
{
  "meals": [
    {
      "idMeal": "52964",
      "strMeal": "Smoked Haddock Kedgeree",
      "strDrinkAlternate": null,
      "strCategory": "Breakfast",
      "strArea": "Indian",
      "strInstructions": "Melt 50g butter in a large saucepan (about 20cm across), add 1 finely chopped medium onion and cook gently over a medium heat for 5 minutes, until softened but not browned.\r\n\r\nStir in 3 split cardamom pods, \u00bc tsp turmeric, 1 small cinnamon stick and 2 bay leaves, then cook for 1 minute.\r\n\r\nTip in 450g basmati rice and stir until it is all well coated in the spicy butter.\r\n\r\nPour in 1 litre chicken or fish stock, add \u00bd teaspoon salt and bring to the boil, stir once to release any rice from the bottom of the pan. Cover with a close-fitting lid, reduce the heat to low and leave to cook very gently for 12 minutes.\r\n\r\nMeanwhile, bring some water to the boil in a large shallow pan. Add 750g un-dyed smoked haddock fillet and simmer for 4 minutes, until the fish is just cooked. Lift it out onto a plate and leave until cool enough to handle.\r\n\r\nHard-boil 3 eggs for 8 minutes.\r\n\r\nFlake the fish, discarding any skin and bones. Drain the eggs, cool slightly, then peel and chop.\u2028\r\n\r\nUncover the rice and remove the bay leaves, cinnamon stick and cardamom pods if you wish to. Gently fork in the fish and the chopped eggs, cover again and return to the heat for 2-3 minutes, or until the fish has heated through.\r\n\r\nGently stir in almost all the 3 tbsp chopped fresh parsley, and season with a little salt and black pepper to taste. Serve scattered with the remaining parsley and garnished with 1 lemon, cut into wedges.",
      "strMealThumb": "https:\/\/www.themealdb.com\/images\/media\/meals\/1550441275.jpg",
      "strTags": "Brunch,Fish,Fusion",
      "strYoutube": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=QqdzDCWS4gQ",
      "strIngredient1": "Butter",
      "strIngredient2": "Onion",
      "strIngredient3": "Cardamom",
      "strIngredient4": "Turmeric",
      "strIngredient5": "Cinnamon Stick",
      "strIngredient6": "Bay Leaf",
      "strIngredient7": "Basmati Rice",
      "strIngredient8": "Chicken Stock",
      "strIngredient9": "Smoked Haddock",
      "strIngredient10": "Eggs",
      "strIngredient11": "Parsley",
      "strIngredient12": "Lemon",
      "strIngredient13": "",
      "strIngredient14": "",
      "strIngredient15": "",
      "strIngredient16": "",
      "strIngredient17": "",
      "strIngredient18": "",
      "strIngredient19": "",
      "strIngredient20": "",
      "strMeasure1": "50g",
      "strMeasure2": "1 chopped",
      "strMeasure3": "3 Pods",
      "strMeasure4": "1\/4 tsp",
      "strMeasure5": "1 small",
      "strMeasure6": "Sprigs of fresh",
      "strMeasure7": "450g",
      "strMeasure8": "1 Litre",
      "strMeasure9": "750g",
      "strMeasure10": "3",
      "strMeasure11": "3 tblsp chopped",
      "strMeasure12": "1 chopped",
      "strMeasure13": " ",
      "strMeasure14": " ",
      "strMeasure15": " ",
      "strMeasure16": " ",
      "strMeasure17": " ",
      "strMeasure18": " ",
      "strMeasure19": " ",
      "strMeasure20": " ",
      "strSource": "https:\/\/www.bbcgoodfood.com\/recipes\/2256\/smoked-haddock-kedgeree",
      "strImageSource": null,
      "strCreativeCommonsConfirmed": null,
      "dateModified": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I keep getting undefined as the array has only one object -> 0, that one random meal, so I'm very confused about how to pull that info out. I created a button that should generate these things on the page, hence the HTML inside.

Comment: I would suggest to add to your question some of the content output from that console.log(r), it will make things easier to us to help you.

Comment: According to the [link](https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php) you posted: `meals` is an array with a single object in it. It's not clear to me why you're trying to access indexes such as `meals[34]`

Comment: `strIngredient1`, `strIngredient2`, `strIngredient3`, ... - Who came up with such a terrible format? o.O

Comment: `error: function(data){ ... }` - You should have another look at the documentation of `$.ajax()` and how the `error` callback is called

Comment: Following the above (really really badly designed) api response, the name of the (only) meal is `r.meals[0].strMeal` and the instructions are `r.meals[0].strInstructions`

Comment: @Andreas  I've a feeling it's just a copy of a ISAM type table structure & lazy coders.. :)..

Answer (score 2):

The return has an array of meals, so just access `meals[0].whatever_var_you_want`

eg.

```js
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php",
  success: function(r){
    var meal = r.meals[0];
    $("#random-name").html(meal.strMeal)
    $("#random-description").html(meal.strInstructions);
    $("#random-source").html(meal.strSource)
    $("#random-photo").attr("src", meal.strMealThumb)
  },
  error: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="random-name"></p>
<p id="random-description"></p>
<p id="random-source"></p>
<img id="random-photo"/>
```

Comment: Omg, thank you so much!! I've tried that but through the declaration of those variables and it didn't work. It worked this way tho!!:))

Answer (score 0):

Per [www.themealdb.com](http://www.themealdb.com):

> Lookup a single random meal
> [www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php](http://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php)

> Lookup a selection of 10
> random meals (only available to $2+ Patreon supporters)
> [www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/randomselection.php](http://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/randomselection.php)

So it is expected to have only one object in the array. To have multiple random selections you have to subscribe. And probably your code would look a bit like:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/randomselection.php", //needs subscription
    success: function(r){
    for (let i=0; i<r["meals"].length; i++) { let meal = r["meals"][i].idMeal; let name=r["meals"][i].strMeal; // ... } }
    },
    error: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the `meal` using the syntax r["meals"][0].

Once you have the meal object, you can get the image, name, instructions and source using strMealThumb, strName, strInstructions and strSource respectively.

```js
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php",
    success: function(r) {
        let meal = r["meals"][0];
        let pic = meal.strMealThumb;
        let name = meal.strMeal;
        let instructions = meal.strInstructions;
        let source = meal.strSource
        $("#random-name").html(name)
        $("#random-description").html(instructions)
        $("#random-source").html(source)
        $("#random-photo").attr("src", pic)
    },
    error: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<img id="random-photo" width="80px"/><br>
<b>Name:</b><p id="random-name"></p>
<b>Source:</b><p id="random-source"></p>
<b>Instructions:</b><p id="random-description"></p>
```